# Javascript 3D array and .split() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
    function parser(data){
    var saveSections = data.split("\r");
    var parsed = new Array();
    var tempCatch = "";
    var CatchTwo = [];
    //saveSections[0] = saveSections[0].split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < saveSections.length; i++){
        saveSections[i] = saveSections[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < saveSections.length; j++){
            tempCatch = saveSections[0][0].split(":");
            //saveSections[0][0] = tempCatch;

        }

    }
    return tempCatch;
}
```

Ok there is problem. This function works without problems until I uncomment

`//saveSections[0][0] = tempCatch;`.

When  I do it, debbuger throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: saveSections[0][0].split is not a function
```

That points at this line:

```
tempCatch = saveSections[0][0].split(":");
```

Comment: You've to iterate the third depth too, arrays have not `split` method.

Comment: But I'm spliting elemment of 2D array. It will be 3D AFTER splitting.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the input this function gets?

Comment: It contains chars that will not be shown here. It's part of encryption algorithm. :(

D:Ch,XPL:1,XPS:987654321,XPE:987654320,E:0,C:2,AC:1,P:0,G:,A:1,S:1,HC:1,H:1,SCO:1,SCR:1,K:2,B:0,BT:0,IP:94.231.225.11,ID:0,IS:1,CM:0D:Eq,I:1,T:1,L:1,C:BBAAD:Eq,I:2,T:2,L:1,C:QIAAD:In,I:25,T:7,Q:30D:Op,M:1,S:1,P:1D:SP,S:BBBBBBBB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample data you gave, the problem is that you're always assigning `tempCatch` to the first item in the 2D array (`saveSections[0][0]`), at the second iteration the `split()` function fails because that's an array, not a string.

This code should iterate on all items:

```
function parser(data){
    var saveSections = data.split("\r");
    var parsed = [];
    var tempCatch = "";
    var CatchTwo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < saveSections.length; i++){
      saveSections[i] = saveSections[i].split(",");
      for (var j = 0; j < saveSections[i].length; j++){
          tempCatch = saveSections[i][j].split(":");
          saveSections[i][j] = tempCatch;
      }
    }
    return saveSections;
}
```

I would assume you need to return `saveSections` instead of `tempCatch`, but that's a bit unclear from your implementation.